# How to open a new blank document in Pages from spotlight?

Tags: spotlight, pages

How can i open a new blank document in Pages app on Mac OSX Yosemite in Spotlight (and therefore in Alfred)?

Now, when i open Pages it first presents me with New document dialog and then Select Template dialog. Of course i click my way through all the prompts but it would be much more convenient to bring up Spotlight (or better yet Alfred) and just type something like Pages /n and go straight to typing.

Comment: And Terminal command to do the same would be great, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem can be eliminated by selecting a default template in the **Preferences**.

[image: Pages preferences]

Then, when opening from **Spotlight** or **Alfred**, a click on the new document button opens your default template.  [Blank in the case of the setting shown above.]

Then, one could create an **Automator** or **Applescript** workflow that is attached to a service evoked by a keystroke combination.

---

Edit: OP @Rusl added this Applescript to a keystroke combination.

```
tell application "Pages"
  activate
  make new document
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for making me think in right direction. Here is the Apple Script that I've bound to a shortcut that will open a blank new Page document. Also, if I run this script from Alfred it will also open a blank new Page document.

`tell application "Pages"
    activate
    make new document
end tell`

Comment: Great!  I'll add your script to the answer for future reference.